# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Are the linear transformations, and the automorphisms
of the form $\sigma(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (x_1 -f(x_2, \dots, x_n), x_2, \dots, x_n)$, where $f$ is a polynomial, generators of the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$?

If this is true, where can I find a good reference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is apparently yes for $n = 2$ but no for $n = 3$. See [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2004-17-01/S0894-0347-03-00440-5/S0894-0347-03-00440-5.pdf).